# Get Current Value of RibbonSpinEditItem

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a ribbon with a RibbonSpinEditItem that needs to display/set the number of minutes before a user is automatically logged out if he's been idle for that time.

At the moment it's configured as below:

```
    themeGroup.Items.Add(MVCxRibbonItemType.SpinEditItem, i =>
    {
        var spin = (RibbonSpinEditItem) i;
        spin.Text = "Log out after: ";
        spin.Name = "TimeBeforeIdle";
        spin.PropertiesSpinEdit.MaxValue = 60;
        spin.PropertiesSpinEdit.MinValue = 5;
        spin.Size = RibbonItemSize.Small;
        spin.Value = ModelSessionHelper.TimeBeforeIdle;
        spin.PropertiesSpinEdit.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = "function(s,e){ alert("+ spin.Value + "); }";
    });
```

The problem now is when I change the value of my item it still alerts the first value.

Example:

Original time: alert 20

+1: alert 20

+1: alert 20

Change to 50: alert 20

I'm guessing this is because the function with the alert is created at the moment my control gets created and uses the value the control has at that moment. So how do I get the alert to use the current value?

If I have to use the s-parameter from my javascript function could someone please explain how to handle this? Because if I alert(s) I just get *Object [Object]*. And I don't know how to get the value of the control out of it?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GetValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientEditBase_GetValuetopic) method:

```
spin.PropertiesSpinEdit.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = "function(s,e) { alert(s.GetValue()); }";
```